# Redirects & Non Browser created POSTS

Tags: php

I have a script which logs some stuff into a database.  At the start of the script I have some code which tests a session to determine if a user is logged in - and if not - redirects them to the front page.

```
if (!$_SESSION['user']['loggedin'] || $_SESSION['user']['access_level'] < ACCESSLEVEL_ACOUNT_MANAGER) {
    redirect('../index.php');
}
```

But - I'm getting odd entries into the database that are coming from this script.  That I know for sure.  I've set up a routine that emails me when an entry is made telling me the values of those sessions - and they're blank.

If a POST does not come from a browser - will the redirect be ignored and will the rest of the script be processed?

--

Edit - here's the redirect function (prior to me adding the exit) which was the culprit.

```
function redirect($url) {

    session_write_close();

    if (true || headers_sent()) {
        print "<script langauge=\"JavaScript\">window.location='$url';</script>";
    } else {
        header("Location: $url");
    }
    header("Location: $url");
}
```

Comment: What is `redirect()`?

Comment: redirect is a function another developer put in.  Basically just sets a few variables and then does a header redirect.

Comment: Does redirect() exit? Usually, after you send a redirect header, you want to explicitly exit your script. If that's not happening, the rest of the script will continue to execute as normal.

Comment: Handn't thought of that - let me check -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a POST does not come from a browser

The type of client that makes an HTTP request is largely irrelevant.

The significant part here is that `$_SESSION['user']['loggedin']` is empty, so the `if` passes and the `redirect` function is called.

> will the redirect be ignored

The redirect function will be called.

The client may or may not follow the instruction from the server to request a different URL instead.

> and will the rest of the script be processed?

The behaviour will be the same as for a browser.

There's nothing in the question to tell us what the `redirect` function does.

It might `exit`, in which case anything after the `if` statement will not be processed.

It might not.

… but the result will be the same for any kind of HTTP client. Browsers are not a special case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Let me check the redirect function to make sure it exits.

Comment: Yep - that was it.  The redirect function did not have an exit call.